# Gmail is blocking email from my application server

Tags: email, smtp, spf, email-bounces

I'm getting the following in my mail logs on my app server:

> 550-5.7.1 [67.23.15.78] The IP you're using to send mail is not authorized to 550-5.7.1 send email directly to our servers. Please use the SMTP relay at your 550-5.7.1 service provider instead. Learn more at 550 5.7.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=10336

I've checked and the IP is not listed on any PBL/SBL/etc that I know of. The domain name in the FROM: email address is a CNAME to our app server's primary domain (djangostage.farstarserver.com). We have a PTR record for the server's IP, so reverse DNS resolves to the same domain (djangostage.farstarserver.com). We also have the following SPF record set up for the domain to allow our vhost domains on that server to send email under their own domains:

```
"v=spf1 a a:django.farstarserver.com -all"
```

Any ideas why Google is blocking our server?

Comment: Is there any spam filter connected?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try clicking on the link in your question?  It explains the situation rather nicely.

In addition to being blocked by Gmail, your IP is listed in [the SpamHaus PBL](http://www.spamhaus.org/pbl/query/PBL339729).  The same range is probably listed in similar DNSBLs run by other organisations.  If you want to reliably send mail from this IP address, you will have to contact *all* of them.

SpamHaus suggest you read the [RackSpace AUP](http://www.rackspace.com/information/legal/aup) before requesting removal.  I would recommend finding a different IP to send mail from.

Talk to Slicehost/Rackspace.  Use their SMTP relay or upgrade your package to one that is allowed to send mail.

Note that it is practically impossible to send email from an EC2 IP address too.  That's why Amazon run SES.

Comment: I don't think the link explains it very well -- it doesn't say the real reason I was blocked, other than "the IP is not authorized". Well, how does one become authorized? Also, it's Rackspace cloud -- and yes, I've  put in a support ticket. They said to contact Google (which, as most people know, is a dead end).

Comment: Spamhaus is the only blacklist: http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3a67.23.15.78#

Comment: I checked the IP, it is not listed on any spamhaus blacklists.

Comment: @BenDavis Yes it is.  [It's in the PBL](http://www.spamhaus.org/query/ip/67.23.15.78).  Regardless of that, Google don't use SpamHaus so requesting removal from the Spamhaus PBL won't help your deliverability at Gmail.

Comment: Odd, I could have sworn when I checked that it was not listed. I have no idea why I didn't see it earlier (perhaps I typed the wrong IP). I'll try it anyway and see. Are you sure they don't use Spamhaus in any way?  I know that spamhaus keeps a list of blocks of IPs that are considered "non-commercial", and as I've recently learned, the ip's rackspace hands out for its cloud servers are included in those blocks.